# Hide Progress bar on form load

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm creating a c# application.

I want to hide the progress bar on form load. So i use this piece of code.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   progressBar1.Visible = false;
}
```

But the progress bar still shows up on form load.

Any help ??

Answer (score 0):

Can't we try setting the visibility of the progress bar to hidden state by default and making it visible when ever you need it in the application?